# Numpy - correlation coefficient and related statistical functions don't give same results

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, correlation

For data `X = [0,0,1,1,0]`and `Y = [1,1,0,1,1]`

```
>> np.corrcoef(X,Y)
```

returns

```
array([[ 1.        , -0.61237244],
       [-0.61237244,  1.        ]])
```

However, I cannot reproduce this result using `np.var` and `np.cov` given the equation shown in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html:

```
>> np.cov([0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1])/sqrt(np.var([0,0,1,1,0])*np.var([1,1,0,1,1]))

array([[ 1.53093109, -0.76546554],
       [-0.76546554,  1.02062073]])
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because, `np.var` default delta degrees of freedom is `0`, not `1`.

```
In [57]:

X = [0,0,1,1,0]
Y = [1,1,0,1,1]
np.corrcoef(X,Y) 
Out[57]:
array([[ 1.        , -0.61237244],
       [-0.61237244,  1.        ]])
In [58]:

V = np.sqrt(np.array([np.var(X, ddof=1), np.var(Y, ddof=1)])).reshape(1,-1)
np.matrix(np.cov(X,Y))
Out[58]:
matrix([[ 0.3 , -0.15],
        [-0.15,  0.2 ]])
In [59]:

np.matrix(np.cov(X,Y))/(V*V.T)
Out[59]:
matrix([[ 1.        , -0.61237244],
        [-0.61237244,  1.        ]])
```

Or looks it the otherway:

```
In [70]:

V=np.diag(np.cov(X,Y)).reshape(1,-1) #the diagonal elements
In [71]:

np.matrix(np.cov(X,Y))/np.sqrt(V*V.T)
Out[71]:
matrix([[ 1.        , -0.61237244],
        [-0.61237244,  1.        ]])
```

What is really going on, `np.cov(m, y=None, rowvar=1, bias=0, ddof=None)`, when `bias` and `ddof` both not provided, the default normalization is by `N-1`, N being the number of observation. So, that is equivalent to have delta degrees of freedom of `1`. Unfortunately, the default for `np.var(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False)` has the default delta degrees of freedom of `0`.

Whenever unsure, the safest way is to grab the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix rather than calculate `var` separately, to ensure consistent behavior.

Comment: 2 quick and possibly elementary questions: Why are you multiplying V with its transpose instead of just multiplying the two variances? And what's the significance of ddof, in particular, when I do set it to 1 instead of the default 0?

Comment: If you just `V*V`, it is going to be an elememnt-wise operation and the result is not the 2-by-2 matrix we want. The second question see https://www.msu.edu/user/sw/statrev/strv155.htm (sample variance v.s. population variance). But that's not the exact issue here, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

According to your link (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) you need to be mindful of the indices...

```
c = np.cov([0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1])
corrcoef = [[ c[0,0]/np.sqrt(c[0,0]*c[0,0]), c[0,1]/np.sqrt(c[0,0]*c[1,1]) ],
           [ c[1,0]/np.sqrt(c[1,1]*c[0,0]), c[1,1]/np.sqrt(c[1,1]*c[1,1]) ]]

print corrcoef
# [[1.0, -0.61237243569579447], [-0.61237243569579447, 1.0]]
```

It's right!